# How do I upload file with specific keyword in name to SFTP with WinSCP

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I currently have a working script that upload files to a SFTP remote sirectory. The problem I am having is that there will be 3 files and they should be uploaded in sequence at different intervals. I have already thought about using Windows Task Scheduler as to take care of the frequency of the upload but there is another issue.  I have identified that the files differ in naming based on one keyword. Is there a way I can modify my code to look for the files in the directory by a particular name? For example it searches in the directory for a file with "customer" in its name. Based on that keyword/name it then uploads that particular file. Please see current working script:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "server"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "key"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Upload files
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

    $transferResult =
        $session.PutFiles("E:\CMBPAID", "/NESAMSCARIMED", $False, $transferOptions)

    # Throw on any error
    $transferResult.Check()

    # Print results
    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
    }
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_file_list You could change the `Get-Content` to a `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*customer*" or something else.

Comment: Umm... Those credentials are valid. You should remove those and change them _NOW_.I removed them from the post and flagged so a mod can remove it from history. I would also change your ssh key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) `*customer*`:

```
$transferResult =
    $session.PutFiles("E:\CMBPAID\*customer*", "/NESAMSCARIMED/", $False, $transferOptions)
```

*(note the slash added to the end of the target path)*